# PHP Multi Curl is Running Very Slow On High Traffic Server Cluster

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

running into speed issues with multi curl. I am using multi curl to grab XML from various urls, all with response times of under 300ms. But my multi curl function is taking over 1 second to grab these URLS (About 10-15 URLS only). Below is the code I am using:

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

    // array of curl handles
    $curly = array();
    // data to be returned
    $result = array();

    // multi handle
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    // loop through $data and create curl handles
    // then add them to the multi-handle
    foreach ($data as $id => $d) {

    $curly[$id] = curl_init();

    $url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 750);


    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
    }

    // execute the handles
    do {
        curl_multi_select($mh, .01);
        $status = curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    } while ($status === CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM || $running);


    // get content and remove handles
    foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
        if(curl_errno($c) == 0)
            $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
        curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
    }

    // all done
    curl_multi_close($mh);

    return $result;
}
```

Is there anything I should be doing to speed this up? My clients throw away the request if it takes over 500ms to complete, so I want to get it to run as long as the longest request takes. I have the timeout set to 750ms, because even though the request times are less then 300ms, my function returns no results if below 750ms.

Answer (score -1):

Lower this then  curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 750); to 500MS